Are the 70 weeks, what restrains iniquity, for the man of sin to be revealed in 2 Thes.2.6-7?
I noticed that the word (H3607) translated "finish" transgression in (Dan.9.24), is translated "restrain" in several other places in the bible (H3607, cp. Genesis 8:2); this, along with the fact that Paul is quoting from Daniel (11.36; 2 Thes.2.4), makes me think Paul had this word, in this verse in mind, when he spoke of that which restrains or withholds in 2 Thes.2.6-7.
(Below is my translation, following the exact word arrangement of the Masoratic text)
Dan.9.24: there are H5921 separated H2852 seventy H7657 weeks H7620; for the holy H6944 city H5892 (old Jerusalem); and for your people H5971; [to put an end] [ולחת] to the rebellion 6588; and to restrain H3607 sin H2304. These sins H2304 ( חטאות is doubled in Heb., and not rendered in the A.V) will be brought to an end H2856 at the coming H935 punishment H5771; which will be for purging H3722, cp. Dan.12.10).
2 Thessalonians 2:6-7

6 And now ye know what withholdeth that he might be revealed in his time.
7 For the mystery of iniquity doth already work: only he who now letteth will let, until he be taken out of the way

I believe that 2 Thess. 2.7; has been mistranslated; the later part should read: "until (G2193) from (G1537) the midst (G3319, cp. Mt.10.16) be fulfilled" (G1096, cp. Mt.5.18); possibly meaning when the fulfillment of the 70 weeks draw close; out from that time, the man of the sin, will be revealed, where he will even claim to be above every God, in the temple of God. At this time there will no restraint upon the iniquity of the people (Mt.24.12; cf. Dan.8.23), and they will worship the beast (Rev.13.4)?
This is the seeming reason for that which restrains in v6., being in the neuter form (the focus is on the time "be revealed in his time" that God has set; and the masculine form is in v7.  i.e  the focus is on God who has decreed, the 70 weeks of time, that are determined to restrain the iniquity, until out
from the mist of their fullfilment (i.e. the final week), the son of perdition will be revealed, and iniquity shall abound (2 Thes.2.3; Mt.24.12)

Here is the literal BLB translation of 2 Thess 2:6, 7 -

And now you know that which is restraining for his being revealed in
his time.  For the mystery of lawlessness is working already; there is
only the one at present restraining it, until he might be gone out of
the midst.

I fail to see an immediate connection between 2 Thess 2 and Dan 9:24 because there is almost nothing common in the language/vocabulary.  However, both speak about restraint but:

in Dan 9:24 it is transgression/sin that is to be finished/restrained
in 2 Thess 2:6, 7 it is the man of lawlessness that is to be restrained

Therefore, Dan 924ff is discussing the time of probation for the Jewish people; by contrast, 2 Thess 2 is discussing a prophecy about an antichrist figure called the "man of lawlessness" with the restraint appearing to be divine power.
APPENDIX - Dan 9:24
Here is my overly literal translation of dan 9:24 showing the underlying Hebrew word structure:
70 weeks are determined for

A: Your people [2 word phrase]


B:  Your Holy City [3 word phrase]


A: Finish/restrain the-transgression, end sin, expiate iniquity [2 word phrases]


B: Introduce eternal righteousness, seal vision & prophecy, anoint most holy [3 word phrases]





Daniel 9:24 -“Seventy weeks are determined for your people and
for your holy city,

to finish the transgression, and
to make an end of sins, and
to make reconciliation for iniquity, and
to bring in everlasting righteousness, and
to seal up the vision and prophecy, and
to anoint the most Holy place.”


We can see some of these occurred during Jesus' 3 1/2 years' service:

Jesus finished transgression [Hebrews 9:26] on the cross
Jesus made an end of sins [Romans 8:3] on the cross
Jesus made reconciliation for iniquity [2 Corinthians 5:19] by his cross
Jesus brought in everlasting righteousness [Ephesians 4:10], though it has yet to be consummated at his final return to Earth [Isaiah 11:6-9]
The finality of vision and prophecy will be in the future [Revelation 10:7]
To anoint the most Holy place also appears to me to be in the future [Revelation 11:19]

Granted - some of the occurrences above that have already taken place will have some continued future fulfillment as well.
2 Thessalonians 2:7 starts with "For the mystery of lawlessness is already at work ...", which shows that sin was happening even then during the time of Paul. Sin abounds in the Earth at the behest of humans still reigning here. As to what is restraining the full revelation of the Antichrist, the scriptures do not clearly show us.
Perhaps misdirection is keeping us from seeing the important piece: our partaking of as much of the cross as possible while we wait for our final salvation.

Therefore He is also able to save to the uttermost those who come to
God through Him, since He always lives to make intercession for them.
[Hebrews 7:25]
In this manner Christ was offered once to bear the sins of many. To
those who eagerly wait for Him He will appear a second time, apart
from sin, for salvation. [Hebrews 9:28]


Seventy Weeks The restraint of Paul's epistle could not be a reference to Daniel's 70 weeks because that lies outside the 70 week time period. The Seventy Week prophecy of Daniel covered the time from the Decree to rebuild the city and Temple...through the Silent Years...to the appearance of Messiah (30 A.D).
REBUILDING...........................................SILENT YEARS.....................................................MESSIAH
(..................................................................... 70 WEEKS...........................................................................)
As the other answer noted, the list of six accomplishments in Daniel find their fulfilment in the ministry of the Anointed One (Messiah Jesus). This was the 3 1/2 year ministry that was cut short in the "middle of the last week" by the crucifixion of Christ.
Future Conflict So the "restraint" and "mystery of iniquity" that Paul referred to was future in his day.  And some may consider the soon-coming Destruction of Jerusalem and the Temple---with all its chaos, rioting, Zealotry, partisanship, famine, and bloodshed---to be in mind. Paul was living on the cusp of the most devastating era of Jewish history that Jesus described as:

For then there will be great tribulation, such as has not been from the beginning of the world until now, nor will be. (Matthew 24:21)

To be sure this Destruction of the Temple complex was linked to the horrible "cutting off of the Messiah", as well as the mistreatment of all the prophets that had gone on before. (Matthew 23:32-38) But this wasn't to occur until 67 -70 A.D.---outside the 70 year time zone. And this may be what Paul was anticipating.
